# Better to reference field instance or parameter in this constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-optimization

I've written this 'CoreException' `Exception` subclass. I appear to have three options in the constructor that would all behave identically since they are all referencing the same object.

*note: the question is about the compiler and possible runtime difference from the three different source code options. The constructed Object could be of any class.

```java
public class CoreException extends Exception {

    private final Class<?> sourceClass;
    private final Method sourceMethod;

    public CoreException(@NotNull Method method, @NotNull Throwable thr) {
        super("this text is irrelevant", thr);

        this.setStackTrace(thr.getStackTrace());
        this.sourceMethod = method;
        this.sourceClass = this.sourceMethod.getDeclaringClass();
    }

    public Class<?> getSourceClass() { return sourceClass; }
    public Method getSourceMethod() { return sourceMethod; }
}
```

The construction of the `Class<?> sourceClass` object seems to have three identical options:

```java
this.sourceClass = this.sourceMethod.getDeclaringClass();
```

```java
this.sourceClass = sourceMethod.getDeclaringClass();
```

```java
this.sourceClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
```

Is there a decent reason to use one over the others, perhaps because of a marginal increase in performance, reliability / resilience, etc..?

Or does the compiler simply turn all three of these into *exactly* the same result?

Comment: They're all the same object.

Comment: yes exactly. this is why I wonder if there is some other reason to use one syntax over the other in this case. Perhaps someone who has a super deep understanding of the compiler / jvm might suggest that one would shave off a few nanoseconds or something. :) (or does the compiler just end up compiling into the same end state exactly?)

Comment: because i mean aren't the first two a reference to a clone of the object instance provided as arg and the third is a reference the specific object instance provided as arg?

Comment: As a first step you could take a look at the generated byte code. Even if you don't understand any of it you should be able to see if there are differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, there is no difference between `this.sourceMethod` and `sourceMethod`, the resulting bytecode will be the same. It is just a matter of taste which you prefer. Some people prefer using `this.` always, while others prefer to only use `this.` when it is necessary for disambiguation if there is also a local variable with the same name.

The only real difference is between `[this.]sourceMethod` and `method`: `sourceMethod` is a field on the object, while `method` is a parameter. Given `method` is a parameter, it's on the stack, and it's probably slightly faster than accessing the field `sourceMethod` of the object. However, in the grand scheme of things, this difference is likely negligible, and even if it's not, it is entirely possible that the JIT compiler optimizes it in a way they are equivalent. If you really need to know, you should write a micro-benchmark to measure that difference.

Personally, I would consider the choice between using `sourceMethod` or `method` primarily one of opinion.

Comment: huge thanks! this helps me understand much better :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a bad idea. You're trying to address a thing you find uncomfortable about java, the language, with an API update. This cannot work - the vast majority of exceptions out there just will not be wrapped in a CoreException (e.g. anything that the java core API itself throws, or anything in any third party library such as JUnit, JDBI, etcetera).

Your code will no longer be making sense to other java programmers who do not expect to need to reroute all exceptions through this class of yours.

You also won't be able to write code that 'fits' in existing APIs (i.e. implementations of interfaces), as you will be required to write your own variants of all relevant exception types (as they will need to extend `CoreException` somewhere in the hierarchy, and the exceptions in `java.*` and anything written in e.g. `jdbi.*` wouldn't, and you can't update them to without forking every library you use).

### So what DO I do?

The info you are sticking in that exception message are already available in plain jane exceptions - the first line of the stack trace. It's silly to repeat this information in the message.

If you have some logging or error reporting system where currently you do not have this information, and you want it to, that is a real problem. You've just decided to solve it in an unwieldy and inadvisable way.

Instead, updating whatever that system might be to include the first line of the stacktrace. This is generally not hard, but it depends on where the place is that made you go: "Oof, I could really use the method name here".

Note that going your own way has more downsides than just 'it stands out in existing APIs like a sore thumb'. IDEs will not recognize this and you won't be able to click on the class+methodname in the message to automatically jump to the right file. You need to match the 'style' of what StackTraceElement prints if you want that.

Your code also causes straight up erroneous conclusions. This approach (of having a `Method` object that represents the source) doesn't make much sense when the exception is thrown from within a lambda.

Thus, abort the plan. Whatever you wanted to accomplish by making `Method sourceMethod` part of the state of all of your exceptions - you either didn't want that, or you can accomplish it far better in a different way (and probably by relying on `getStackTrace()[0])` to convey it.

```
public Class<?> getSourceClass() {
   return Class.forName(getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());
}
```

can do the job just as well, for example, though note that this code may fail (throw ClassNotFoundEx) depending on where the exception came from. Not all code is easily captured in a 'it is in this class and in this method' context (core stuff, native stuff, synthetic methods, bridgers, dynamically generated code, lambdas...)

Comment: the usecase of this custom exception is constructed and thrown in specific locations. The goal of this exception is to copy the stack from the real exception, and then attach a hard-coded method to the exception. When/if a CoreException is allowed intentionally to reach the Main class, the main class checks all exceptions it receives for being type CoreException.

Comment: if is it CoreException, then it checks for my custom annotations that when present, cause either a server shutdown or restart by design as a result of a specific exception from a specific method.

Comment: the exception will never be thrown from within a lambda and i don't need the method name

Comment: and you have not answered my question

Comment: @DogeCode I have - I told you what you need to be doing. Which is to update your log / print exception code.

Comment: but all the points you made don't relate to the context of the usecase of this code. I shared only enough code and context to ask the question i asked so it's odd you've made so many assumptions including the idea that "the vast majority of exceptions out there just will not be wrapped in a CoreException" somehow matters. In fact, that is actually a feature if anything. There is also no "need to reroute all exceptions through this class of yours." Why would anyone wrap all exceptions into ones that result in an intentional fatal server shutdown via annotated source methods?

Comment: the question was about the performance of three basically identical lines of code.. the code is novel and I'm using it for fun tbh. i'm not writing for a company this is a random addition to a minecraft plugin for learning and playing with coding. the whole exception is admittedly not very useful if at all; was never meant to be.